# Wrong number of arguments( 0 for 2..3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to refactor a string, which I receive as a parameter, into an array of words (using the `split` method).

My `Test` model has one attribute, called `source`.

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :source
  serialize :sources, Array
  after_create do
    test.source.split(' ')
  end
end
```

This returns an error:

> wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)

I can't figure out what arguments Rails wants.

**UPD**

And if I change my code like this:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :source
  serialize :sources, Array
  def split_this_text(test_id)
    @test = Test.where(:test_id=>test_id)
    @test.source.split(' ')
  end
end
```

and call method in tests_controller/create:

```
 @test.split_this_text(:id)
```

Than I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in TestsController#create

undefined method `split' for #<Arel::Nodes::JoinSource:0x4ddfc60>
```

**UPD#2**

Finally works works without any mistakes, but behaves like nothing works and source usuall string (for example `@test.source[0]` returns a letter)

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :source
  serialize :sources, Array
  before_save :split_this_text
  def split_this_text
    self.source.split(' ')
 end
end
```

Comment: Your second error of undefined method 'split' is because Test.where(:test_id=>test_id) returns an Arel node instead of a single individual Test. You probably want to use Test.find_by_test_id(test_id).

Comment: Thanks... that, at least, let me to step further to the next error, lol)

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that the word "test" is reserved by rails in some way.

One of my model's attribute names was "test". When I tried to call `instance.update_attributes(:test => SOMEVALUE)`, it would return the same *'wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)'* message you were getting.

When I changed the name of the attribute from "test" to something else, the error disappeared.